# JBoss 6x The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Tags: java, jsp, jboss, tags, jstl

I have a web application (its a ear file) in JBoss 6x.

**Error Message on accessing JSP Page:**
The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

**JSP**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app      
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"    
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"     
    version="3.0">
```

**WEB-INF\lib contains**

```
jstl-1.2.jar
```

Please advice, what am i doing wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be with Classloaders behavior in JBoss 6x for .ear (enterprise archive).  My ear file has a war inside it, which ends up using its own classloader - that always looks for jar files only in WEB-INF\lib.

My jstl-1.2.jar was in JBOSS_HOME\server\domain\lib 
All jars in this location are visible to .ear, but not to the .war inside it. Therefore JSP could not find jstl-1.2.jar

Once i placed the jstl-1.2.jar in WEB-INF\lib in the war, the error went away.
This explains the problem and immediate solution.

Although i would like to have a single class-loader for the entire .ear (not a different one for .war) - not sure how to do that - but that is a different question.